# Concatenating multiple fields in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I am working on a Windows Forms application in which I have a form for an inmate that takes all the basic information about the inmate and his home address and everything.

I have two comboboxes, one is a parent combobox for State and the other one is a child combobox and that is for City. The values of the City combobox depend on the selected item from the State combobox.

For example, if the **admin** selects "State1" from State comboBox then values in the City comboBox appear like "City1", "City2", "City3" etc. and if the **admin** selects "State2" from State comboBox then the values in the City comboBox appear like "City4", "City5", "City6" etc.

I have this to store the value of the City comboBox:

```
sql_com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City_ComboBox.SelectedItem);
```

All I want to know is, is there a way to concatenate multiple fields in this code. Say, I have multiple City comboBoxes by the name "City_ComboBox1", "City_ComboBox2" and "City_ComboBox3".

Is there a way I can do something like this:

```
sql_com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City_ComboBox1.SelectedItem + City_ComboBox2.SelectedItem + City_ComboBox3.SelectedItem);
```

But I get an error.

Comment: Are you going to save all the selected cities in a single field? While its's not a good idea for a relational database, but if you want to do so, at least you need to use a separator like `,` between city names.

Comment: do you have several comboboxes on the form to store the several selected cities? Ok, you can take all selected cities to the string. But how will you use this string you saved in the db with names concatenated one by one ? You have to use some separator (as @RezaAghaei said) or to put dedicated sql parameter (and sql field) to store each city separately in the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. One is with the `string.Format()` method.

```
string cityString = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", City_ComboBox1.SelectedItem, City_ComboBox2.SelectedItem, City_ComboBox3.SelectedItem);
sql_com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", cityString);
```

string.Format let's you create a template of sorts for how you want the string to look. You use the placeholder `{#}` with the number that corresponds to the index of the values you pass in. And you can use those placeholders multiple times within the template. Anything that you pass into the method after the first string value, gets converted into a string.

It is also worth noting that while `AddWithValue` is easy to use, it can cause problems as your application grows. It is recommended to use

```
sql_com.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = cityString;
```

But you will replace the `NVarChar` and `64` with values that match your database column set up. See https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way is to use the `Interpolated Strings` with the `$` sign as the following:

```
string cityString = $"{City_ComboBox1.SelectedItem} {City_ComboBox2.SelectedItem} {City_ComboBox3.SelectedItem}";
sql_com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", cityString);
```

by adding `$` in front of the string and inside this string just put any variable within the curly braces `{variableName}`

Comment: Are you going to write new code each time new record is added to the combobox?

Comment: I think they have a constant number of combo boxes so the programmer can always check if there is a value and add it to the string, if the number of the combo boxes is dynamic, we can loop through these combo boxes using the index and add it to the string.

Answer (score 0):

**string.Concat**

```
sql_com.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = string.Concat(City_ComboBox1.SelectedItem, City_ComboBox2.SelectedItem, City_ComboBox3.SelectedItem)
```

**string.join**

```
var join = ",";
    sql_com.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = string.Join(join  ,City_ComboBox1.SelectedItem, City_ComboBox2.SelectedItem, City_ComboBox3.SelectedItem)
```